# Effect of class_weight and sample_weight in Keras

Tags: keras

Can someone tell me mathematically how sample_weight and class_weight are used in Keras in the calculation of loss function and metrics? A simple mathematical express will be great.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a simple multiplication. The loss contributed by the sample is magnified by its sample weight. Assuming `i = 1 to n` samples, a weight vector of sample weights `w` of length `n`, and that the loss for sample `i` is denoted `L_i`:

[image]

In Keras in particular, the product of each sample's loss with its weight is divided by the fraction of weights that are not 0 such that the loss per batch is proportional to the number of weight > 0 samples. Let `p` be the proportion of non-zero weights.

[image]

Here's the relevant snippet of code from the Keras repo:

```
score_array = loss_fn(y_true, y_pred)

if weights is not None:
    score_array *= weights
    score_array /= K.mean(K.cast(K.not_equal(weights, 0), K.floatx()))

return K.mean(score_array)
```

`class_weight` is used in the same way as `sample_weight`; it is just provided as a convenience to specify certain weights across entire classes.

The sample weights are currently not applied to metrics, only loss.

Comment: So given `L`, does Keras compute the derivatives based on the weighted loss or the unweighted loss is used only?